# How to run loop downward until cells to the right are empty - VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I am running a loop that enters a formula, copies it, then goes to the next line, checks if the 2 cells to the right are empty, if they are, then do nothing. If they contain anything at all, then paste formula (word "true" in below example) from B10.

However it pastes the formula, then stops. It doesn't keep looping down until the cells to the right are empty?

Any idea's on how to fix this would be appreciated!

```
Sub Macro1()

Range("B10").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "TRUE"
Range("B10").Select
Selection.Copy

Range("B11").Select

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("B11:B150")

If IsEmpty(cell.Offset(0, 3).Value) = True Then
cell.Value = ""

Else: ActiveSheet.Paste

End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn’t enter a formula anywhere. Do you mean enters the value TRUE?

Comment: wherever you see select, you can basically delete that part, and then drop the part before the period in the next line and combine it as one line.  `RANGE("B10").Value = "True"` is the better way of doing it

Comment: Delete the line `RANGE("B11").select`  You select it and then do not do anything with it.  I could step through without error when I deleted that line.

Comment: urdearboy, yes I replaced the actual formula with the words "true" for this example as it was too long and complicated and didn't add to the example at all.

Comment: Forward Ed, Thanks! I thought there was a shorter way or writing it! just didn't know how! Any idea's why it isn't looping though?

Answer (score 1):

This should do... notice that you do not need `.Select`

---

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = ThisworkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim myCell as Range

For Each myCell in ws.Range("B10:B150")
    If myCell.Offset(,1) <> "" and myCell.offset(,2) <> "" Then
        myCell = "TRUE"
    End If
Next myCell

End Sub
```

Comment: not a VBA programmer but are you missing a character before the comma in the offset line?

Comment: Updated. You can make it (0, 3) but the `0` is not necessary

Comment: Thanks Urdearboy, however it stopped and highlighted the same line as my last question earlier today.

Comment: Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Client - Order Status Summary") - I changed it to the right sheet name.....

Comment: As it still wouldn't work I changed the name of the worksheet to "Sheet1", and made sure it was copied as you suggested above, and then it stopped throwing up the error - however still won't add "TRUE" to the worksheet?

Comment: @PaulOmeara I updated urdearboy's code slightly by changing the IF line.  It did work for the brief bit of sample data I had on Sheet1

Comment: Sorry I typed this up on my phone so did not have the auto correct syntax thing going. :|

Comment: @urdearboy I made the initial mistake of 2 and 3 hope you did not mind the edit to 1 and 2 and the <>""

Comment: Hmm, Nope, still not working for me? Does it matter what version of excel I am using? (2013)